# unable to add cucumber to cypress

Tags: configuration, cucumber, cypress

I have a problem with setting up / adding cucumber to cypress.
I am getting the following error:
Error: Step implementation missing for: I am on the link
at Context.resolveAndRunStepDefinition (http://localhost:58088/__cypress/test
at Context.eval (http://localhost:58088/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration

PACKAGE.JSON:

```
   {
  "scripts": {
    "cypress-open": "cypress open",
    "cypress-feature": "cypress run --spec **/*.feature"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.6.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "cypress-xpath": "^1.6.2"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
}
```

CYPRESS.JSON

```
{

    "testFiles" :"**/*.feature"   
    }
```

[files tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVUCv.png)

Answer (score 0):

To run the `user.feature`, the `user.js` step should be in the `user` folder.

"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1" is really old version.

Recommend "badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.3.0" for latest bug fixes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, you have to add in your `/plugins/index.js` following code.

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor